# How to make a copy of a JSONDecoder instance?

Tags: swift

I would like to have different variations of `JSONDecoder` instances copying from a default one. It seems that `JSONDecoder` is a `class` but there is no `.copy()` API for it.

```
extension JSONDecoder {
    static let `default` = JSONDecoder()
}

let decoder2: JSONDecoder = .default
decoder2.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

print(JSONDecoder.default.keyDecodingStrategy) // convertFromSnakeCase
```

The `decoder2` mutations are applying to `JSONDecoder.default` in this example. How can I make a copy to `decoder2` before mutating it?

Comment: The answer of this question is not making a copy but having multiple static decoders created only once

Comment: I guess even stored in a dictionary, but becomes messy and needs thread-safety :(

Comment: If you are really paranoid about it being changed somewhere eles you can make a wrapper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that there is no copy is that JSONDecoder does not conform to NSCopying. If you are concerned about thread safety and to be able to pass your object without a reference you need a wrapper struct instead of a class and do not expose the decoder declaring it private. This way you will be able to initialize a custom object but you wont be able to change the decoder properties:

```
struct JSONDecoderWrapper {
    private let decoder = JSONDecoder()
}
```

---

```
extension JSONDecoderWrapper {
    init(dataDecodingStrategy: JSONDecoder.DataDecodingStrategy = .base64,
         dateDecodingStrategy: JSONDecoder.DateDecodingStrategy = .deferredToDate,
         keyDecodingStrategy: JSONDecoder.KeyDecodingStrategy = .useDefaultKeys,
         nonConformingFloatDecodingStrategy: JSONDecoder.NonConformingFloatDecodingStrategy = .throw,
         userInfo: [CodingUserInfoKey : Any] = [:]) {
        decoder.dataDecodingStrategy = dataDecodingStrategy
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = dateDecodingStrategy
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = keyDecodingStrategy
        decoder.nonConformingFloatDecodingStrategy = nonConformingFloatDecodingStrategy
        decoder.userInfo = userInfo
    }
}
```

---

```
extension JSONDecoderWrapper {
    /// Summary:
    /// Decodes a top-level value of the given type from the given JSON representation.
    func decode<T>(_ type: T.Type, from data: Data) throws -> T where T : Decodable {
        try decoder.decode(type, from: data)
    }
}
```

---

```
extension JSONDecoderWrapper {
    var dataDecodingStrategy: JSONDecoder.DataDecodingStrategy { decoder.dataDecodingStrategy }
    var dateDecodingStrategy: JSONDecoder.DateDecodingStrategy { decoder.dateDecodingStrategy }
    var keyDecodingStrategy: JSONDecoder.KeyDecodingStrategy { decoder.keyDecodingStrategy }
    var nonConformingFloatDecodingStrategy: JSONDecoder.NonConformingFloatDecodingStrategy { decoder.nonConformingFloatDecodingStrategy }
    var userInfo: [CodingUserInfoKey : Any] { decoder.userInfo }
}
```

---

```
extension JSONDecoderWrapper {
    func copy(dataDecodingStrategy: JSONDecoder.DataDecodingStrategy? = nil,
              dateDecodingStrategy: JSONDecoder.DateDecodingStrategy? = nil,
              keyDecodingStrategy: JSONDecoder.KeyDecodingStrategy? = nil,
              nonConformingFloatDecodingStrategy: JSONDecoder.NonConformingFloatDecodingStrategy? = nil,
              userInfo: [CodingUserInfoKey : Any]? = nil) -> Self {
       .init(dataDecodingStrategy: dataDecodingStrategy ?? decoder.dataDecodingStrategy, dateDecodingStrategy: dateDecodingStrategy ?? decoder.dateDecodingStrategy, keyDecodingStrategy: keyDecodingStrategy ?? decoder.keyDecodingStrategy, nonConformingFloatDecodingStrategy:  nonConformingFloatDecodingStrategy ?? decoder.nonConformingFloatDecodingStrategy, userInfo: userInfo ?? decoder.userInfo)
    }
}
```

---

Playground testing

```
extension JSONDecoderWrapper {
    static let `default` = JSONDecoderWrapper()
}

JSONDecoderWrapper.default

// let decoder2 = JSONDecoderWrapper.default
// decoder2.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase // error Cannot assign to property: 'keyDecodingStrategy' is a get-only property
// decoder2.decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase // error 'decoder' is inaccessible due to 'private' protection level

// you can make a copy changing one or mpore specific properties
let decoder2 = JSONDecoderWrapper.default.copy(keyDecodingStrategy: .convertFromSnakeCase)

print(decoder2.dataDecodingStrategy) // "base64\n"
print(decoder2.dateDecodingStrategy) // deferredToDate\n"
print(decoder2.keyDecodingStrategy) // "convertFromSnakeCase\n"
print(decoder2.nonConformingFloatDecodingStrategy) // "throw\n"
print(decoder2.userInfo) // "[:]\n"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can off course write your own copy method, there are not that many properties to copy. Or if you want to have the same template to start from you can have a factory method to create a decoder with a default configuration

```
extension JSONDecoder {
    //copy
    func copy() -> JSONDecoder {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dataDecodingStrategy = self.dataDecodingStrategy
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = self.dateDecodingStrategy
        //...
        return decoder
    }

    //factory
    static func createDefault() -> JSONDecoder {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dataDecodingStrategy = .base64
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
        //...

        return decoder
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to reuse an instance instead of recreating the instance

Comment: @TruMan1 Then it is not a copy so what do you mean?

Comment: Coming from a value based world, I want to copy it from memory to another variable. Then modify it from the copy without changing the original instance.

Comment: @TruMan1 Then my `copy` method will do that for you.

Comment: Well another example is `DateFormatter` which is expensive to instantiate. So I want to make copies from it without changing the original.

Comment: @TruMan1 You can't make a copy of a class without instantiating a new object.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson you should make JSONDecoder conform to NSCopying. Anyway it wont change the fact that you need a new instance.

Comment: @LeoDabus I had forgotten about that protocol but it's a bit objective-c-ish and you need to cast the result.

Comment: Yes but that’s how it works for all classes